# Parsing a JSON of unknown Structure Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray

I am trying to parse this json and am not sure of parsing this because the keys like "vis-progress-control" might change and I am trying to build a general code which parses this type of a json. I am sure that "type" key will be present in the json structure.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [sData JSONValue];

NSArray *items = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"assets"];

NSLog(@"%@", items);

for (NSString *key in [[dict objectForKey:@"assets"]allKeys]) {

    for (NSString *subKey in [[[dict objectForKey:@"assets"] objectForKey:key]allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"Value at subkey:%@ is %@\n",subKey,[[[dict objectForKey:@"assets"]objectForKey:key]objectForKey:subKey]);

         }
  }
```

I am using the SBJson Library on Github. My actual issue is How do I access "direction", "degrees" etc when I do not know the "vjs-progress-holder" key?
I have also a widgets array nested within a widgets array. How do I get these values as well?

Comment: You're already parsing the JSON into dictionaries and arrays; what more are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get individual elements like colors, borderRadius, ratios, without using the keys like "vis-progress-holder", etc These names might change in a new json file

Comment: Are you just trying to iterate through everything in the assets dictionary? Are you trying to transform this into some different structure?

Comment: @Firoze I am trying to iterate through the entire assets dictionary, to check for the "type", If its of type"gradient" it has some assets like degrees, alphas, ratios etc, But if it of some other type say "image" it has some assets like cornerRadius etc, I am trying to come up with a general parser

Comment: Well, to @JesseRusak's point, you already have a general JSON parser. And you can already print the whole assets dict. So maybe you can say a bit more about specifically what you need to do with each key?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer 1.This is not the complete json file. 2. I need to get hold of "degrees", "colors" etc to define my own asset later. I also have image data which I want to display them on a View

Comment: I am trying to write a for loop and use something like a switch to get the "type" key first and then based on this "type" key I need to extract other parameters.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer I also have a widgets array which is coming in, NSArray does not have a method allValues right? So how do I get the values within the widgets as well?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your objective here, it seems like you want to do something like this?

```
NSDictionary *outerDict = [sData JSONValue];
NSDictionary *assets = outerDict[@"assets"];

for (NSDictionary *asset in [assets allValues]) {

    NSString *type = asset[@"type"];

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"gradient"]) {

        float degrees = [asset[@"degrees"] floatValue];
        // and read whatever other values you need for gradients
    }

    if ([type isEqualToString:@"image"]) {

        // and read the appropriate values for images here... 

    }
}
```

So I'll make a different assumption here, which is that you want an array of gradients. So then that looks basically like this:

```
NSDictionary *outerDict = [sData JSONValue];
NSDictionary *assets = outerDict[@"assets"];
NSMutableArray *gradients = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *asset in [assets allValues]) {

  NSString *type = asset[@"type"];

  if ([type isEqualToString:@"gradient"]) {

    // Add this asset to the list of gradients:
    [gradients addObject:asset];
  }

  if ([type isEqualToString:@"image"]) {

    // do something similar for images

  }
}
```

Then, after having done that, if you would like to read the "degrees" field for the 4th gradient, for example, you will find it at `gradients[3][@"degrees"]`

Comment: sort of something like this. Let me try this if this works for me. Thanks.

Comment: I have almost got it I believe, this type "gradient" is not unique there are almost 8 instances of this? How do I get the corresponding values of each type "gradient"

Comment: This will iterate through each gradient, no matter how many there are.

Comment: Yes I understand that.  Thank you for the code snippet. But I want to extract each degrees value individually. I have used the code you have provided, at this moment it gives me 8 "degrees" values as it is supposed to. My question is as to how do I get each "degrees" value.

Comment: Are you saying you want a method to access the nth gradient? Are you trying to build an array of gradients? It's really hard to know precisely what you mean by "get each 'degrees' value".

Comment: I am trying to get something like this under "vis-progress-control" I have a type "gradient" and it has a degree key, similarly "vjs-progress-control" has a type gradient and a degree key. So how do I get hold of these "degree" uniquely?

Comment: Ok, so let's try this again. Earlier you asked for a for loop to iterate through the gradients. Now it seems you want some other structure. So is it that you want to get the nth gradient? What is the key that you would like to use to retrieve the particular gradient you want?

Comment: This logic will not work for the current json structure right?

Comment: I thought you said it did work? (see your comment before your last one)

Comment: I did not have this current json which I am working on, I have a new structure coming in, which starts with "widgets", yesterday

Comment: The present code logic is not even reading the assets it was reading properly previously

Comment: Well, your JSON has changed since you originally asked the question, so that's not a huge surprise. The best suggestion I can give you is to understand the code that was given, and then use that as a starting point to help you write the code you need for your own specific circumstance.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to understand the code given by you,But I have never come across a nested structure like this, So I am having a hard time accomplishing this

Comment: The widgets here is an array within an array, So if I try using the same logic of reading assets it will fail. So is there a way of converting this array into a dictionary and use the same logic used for the assets? Please comment on this idea

Answer (score 0):

Read about tree traversal.  Sounds like you want to traverse the "tree" of nodes and when you find a particular leaf value you will then traverse back up one level and know the parent is the container you want.

So the idea is that once it's parsed from the JSON, forget it's JSON because now it's just a tree in arrays and dictionaries.  Traverse it by getting all the keys in the dictionary via `allKeys` (returns an array of keys) and then iterate through them getting the associated values (using something like (psuedo code):

```
for ( NSString * key in allkeysarray) { 
  NSString * val = [dict objectForKey: key];
  if ( [val isEqualToString: @"gradient"] )
  {
     // now you know that this dictionary is the one you're looking for so you can maybe break out of this loop and just use the keys you know reference these values.
     break;
  }
}
```

hopefully that's enough to get you going.